# Set Realm object properties with Python

Tags: python, apache-kafka, realm, kerberos

I want to authenticate a Kafka client using a domain account with keytab of the account. How can I set the realm object properties like kdc and admin server using python?

Comment: Did you find the answer helpful for your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This information actually sits in the kerberos configuration file called `krb5.conf` in each server in your cluster - in case of Unix servers, the exact path would be `/etc/krb5.conf`.

These attributes cannot be configured at the client side.

For authenticating your client, you'll just need to:

1. get the principal and the keytab created
2. supply these in a `jaas.conf` file
3. set the properties appropriately to point to the `jaas.conf` and `krb5.conf`

I've tried to simplify the process here but here is a [detailed reference on this subject](https://docs.confluent.io/2.0.0/kafka/sasl.html).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the valuable information. So I will have to deploy Confluent Platform?

Comment: Well. This solution is applicable to all Kafka distributions (open source, Confluent or Cloudera).